# @FetchRequest annotation in SwiftUI with Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

How do I use `@FetchRequest` with a `CoreData` entity `Post` that has `Codegen: Class Def.` set in `Xcode`? So I don't create the `Post`" entity class manually, but let Xcode generate it?

I now get a

> Use of undeclared type `Post`

as an error on the last line.

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Post.entity(), sortDescriptors: [ 
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Post.date, ascending: true)
]) 
var posts: FetchedResults<Post> // Use of undeclared type ´Post´
```

[image: xcdatamodel]

Comment: This looks fine. Can you share the entity, `Post` definition?

Comment: @PankajKulkarni updated with a screenshot of the xcdatamodel

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Since it's a hobby project I've put it on ice at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Core data can be buggy sometimes. Try quitting Xcode and reopening it again.

Comment: This actually helped me.

Comment: I am glad it did